# How can i connect JavaScript and android app together in AWS?

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

I want to develop a simple android + java script web application with AWS services . My aim is to signup a user using an android application with his mobile number , unique Name etc. . I can store these details in AWS DynamoDb service .

Next i am going to login a sample web application with the registered unique Name . I first query to DynamoDB to fetch the user exist or not . if exists , AWS should send a message to the Android Application and if this success , i can access to the sample web page .

**My doubts :**  I can fetch and get the name from DynamoDB using JavaScript . So how can i send a notification to the connected android app from AWS ? if it success , how can i send this response back from AWS to JavaScript ?

Any idea ? which service in AWS should i use ? Any sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a WebView in your Android app, the JS run in the WebView, then search "Android WebView JS interaction" you will get lot samples.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions . But i want to open the web page in another desktop . Now i have one Android app and other is web page . So when i query the name with the webpage , server  should send the message to that app . Can i do with AWS Services ?